# Resharper Test Runner: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows'

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, nunit, resharper

I have an issue with VS2012 and Resharper 7.1.2 at the moment to run unit tests (Nunit).

The complete error message is here:

> Unit Test Runner failed to run tests:
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture =neutral,
> PublicKeyToken= 7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I have upload the last version of Resharper (7.1.2) and i tried use vs2010 but the problem is there yet.
Any help?

Comment: This could be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825743/can-not-find-system-windows-assembly) question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is already known (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-339987) and a pre released version 7.1.3 is downloadable here (http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/ReSharperSetup.7.1.3000.1964.msi).

This version is currently not official.