# Trying to use Application.Current in TestCase, however Application cannot be imported from System.Windows

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I try to unit-test a Gui application code that uses 
`Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()` and would like to use the solution provided by @informatorius in the similar thread [Using the WPF Dispatcher in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106881/using-the-wpf-dispatcher-in-unit-tests). The code is listed below.

The problem I have is that `Application` is not resolved, even if I add `using System.Windows`. Is there some special mechanism to resolve 
`Application` from within a class library that defines the testcases ? 
I have the `MSTest.TestFramework` and `MSTest.TestAdapter` packages installed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestClass] 
public class ApplicationInitializer
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void AssemblyInitialize(TestContext context)
    {
        var waitForApplicationRun = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var application = new Application();
            application.Startup += (s, e) => { waitForApplicationRun.SetResult(true); };
            application.Run();
        });
        waitForApplicationRun.Task.Wait();
    }
    [AssemblyCleanup]
    public static void AssemblyCleanup()
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Application.Current.Shutdown);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        // implementation can access Application.Current.Dispatcher
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825743/can-not-find-system-windows-assembly) pointed me into the right direction:
`using System.Windows` is not enough, I also needed to add reference to `PresentationFramework` to the project. Dont really understand the auto magic behind that.